# How to reverse string word by word in assembly language?

Tags: string, assembly, reverse, emu8086

I want program to reverse string word by word
For example:

input:

Stack overflow

Output:

Kcats wolfrevo

Please help me...

Please fix this code and complete it:

```
.MODEL  SMALL
.stack 64
.DATA
    msg DB "stack owerflow"
        DB "$"
.CODE
    .STARTUP
    LEA SI, msg
    MOV DI, SI
l1:
    INC DI
    MOV AL, [DI + 1]
    CMP AL, ' '
    JNE l1 
l2:
    MOV AL, [SI]
    xchg AL, [DI]
    MOV [SI], AL
    INC SI
    DEC DI
    CMP SI, DI
    JB  l2

l3: 
    MOV AH, 09h
    LEA DX, msg
    INT 21h
    MOV AH, 08h
    INT 21H

.STACK
END
```

Comment: This feels distinctly like a homework assignment.

Comment: What does the code produce at the moment? Have you identified why it does what it does?

Comment: You could write the algorithm in C, then either translate it to assembly, or have the compiler output assembly and clean up the assembly code.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Can you complete it?

Comment: @MTCoster my code output is "kcata owerflow". But i want "kcata wolfrewa". Can you fix and complete it  ?

Comment: @zanyara please put this explanation ***in the question.***

Comment: @zanyara Of course *I* can complete it.  But since it's your homework assignment it somehow seems better that *you* complete it.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I know. But do not have much time and just want it over to my master. I thank you. Please complete it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a request to complete someone's homework assignment and he is unable to identify an actual question beyond "Complete this for me."

Answer (score -1):

Judging by your description of the problem as stated in one of the comments, (please move it to the question,) your routine reverses just one word and then it quits.

And by looking at your code, it is obvious that your routine does precisely that: it reverses just one word and then it quits.

So, you need to add just a little bit of code so that after reversing one word, your routine proceeds to examine the remaining characters instead of just quitting.

I will not write your code for you, because if you do not know how to do that, then you do not deserve to turn in a completed assignment. Your teacher will be grading *you*, not me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10451727)

Comment: @amdixon if you look at the comments, the OP was asked to provide clarification, and he did provide it.  When the question is about homework, the indicated course of action is to indicate what needs to be done, not write their code for them.  That's what I did, so that is the best answer to the question given the homework nature of the question.

Comment: asking to provide clarification is a good use for comments. as is the contents of your answer

Comment: @amdixon you are, of course, entitled to have your opinion on the matter. [The fact that appear to be a minority](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10451727)  does *not* prove that your opinion is invalid, but it does allow me to keep my answer here without altering it or deleting it.

Comment: as the answerer, it is your choice what you do with your answer